# Setting box div background to full white?

Tags: php, html, css, background-color

I am trying to set the background of little sections in this box to white.
[image]
In the image, above the horizontal rule, it says "Test Item", and it has a little white background behind it. I am trying to make the background look like this...
[image]

This is my php file.

```
<div class="containerwhite">
    <div id="container" class="container">
        <?php 
        $sql = "SELECT id, name, description, imgpath, price, sold FROM traceylynn";
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $num = 0;
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<div id="item">';
                    echo '<div class="name">';
                        echo '<p>' .$row["name"].' </p>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    echo '<hr class="namehr">';

                    echo '<div class="price">';
                        echo '<p> $'.$row["price"].'</p>';
                        echo '<hr class="pricehr">';
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="image">';
                        echo '<img alt="Cannot load image" src="'.$row["imgpath"].'"/>';
                    echo '</div>';

                    echo '<div class="button">';
                        if($row["sold"]==0){
                            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal"
                                data-target="#'.$row["id"].'"> More Info </button>';
                        }else{
                            echo '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg disabled"> Sold! </button>';
                        }
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "BlendaScript";
  src: url('../fonts/BlendaScript1.otf') format("opentype");
  src: url('../fonts/BlendaScript2.woff') format("woff"), url('../fonts/BlendaScript3.ttf') format("TrueType"), url('../fonts/BlendaScript4.woff2') format("woff2");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: Sugar;
  src: url('../fonts/Sugar.ttf' format("truetype"));
}

body {
  background-color: #EFC6D3;
}

.containerwhite {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.container {
  margin-bottom: 20px !important;
}

.traceylynnheader {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: BlendaScript;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3D3028;
}

.traceylynnheader hr {
  margin-top: -15px;
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  color: #333;
  /* old IE */
  background-color: #333;
  /* Modern Browsers */
}

#item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  height: 400px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #d0e0aa;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#item>.name {
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-family: Sugar;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #3D3028;
  background-color: white;
}

#item>.name>.namewhite {
  background-color: white;
}

#item>.namehr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #3D3028;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#item>.price {
  text-align: center;
  color: green !important;
  font-family: Sugar;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#item>.price>.pricehr {
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #3D3028;
  margin: 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

Comment: What is the css class / Id of your "Test Item" text container or provide complete DOM with css?

Comment: You'll have a hard time if you use the `hr` tag. Its an old and cruddy tag that comes with terrible padding and styling of its own. You could do the line with a border style, and then the rest is just fiddling with padding and margins. Your PHP really has no bearing on this and it would be far more helpful to just post the end HTML and CSS, and no links to such.

Comment: with `echo '<div id="item">';` in your `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {`, you are going to have a hard time with `#item`, as it is not unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have used `padding-left` and `padding-right` of `30px`in the `#item` div which is obvious that you want the space from left and right in the `#item` div...

...so to make `#item > .name` full width you have to use negative margin *(same value as parent padding)* in the `.name` like

```
#item > .name{
  margin-left:-30px;
  margin-right:-30px;
}
```

Also it looks like you are running a loop of items having `#item` as an `id` which means you will have multiple `id` with same name in the single page which is not a good practice...use `class` instead